# Style UL with Sprite Image

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Wondering if it is possibly to use a sprite image to replace the ul list default bullet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists have the `list-style-image` property, but it is often too inflexible.

You can usually get it working with something like this...

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
}

ul li {
   padding: 3px 0 3px 35px;
   background: url(images/layout/bullet.png) no-repeat left center;
}
```

A sprite is not generally a good idea for this - unless you space them all vertically and allow sufficiently enough vertical margins so the list item doesn't grow too large and have other sprites bleed through.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use background-size with it as well, but that doesn't seem to work when you specify the coordinates of the image.

Answer (score 2):

ya sure its possible

first you remove the bullet style for the li tag

```
list-style:none;
```

Then give `background-image` for the li tag

Comment: And probably a `text-indent` to keep the `<li>` content from appearing on top of the bullet image.